# Looking to calculate the number of items in column 1 that are within a certain date range that is in column 6, using commands

Tags: linux, unix, awk, nlp

So I have a CSV file with 21 columns.  Column 1 is author_ID and column 6 is publish date.  I am looking to output the total number of authors_IDs that are in the date range of 1/1/2017 0:00 to 12/31/2017 24:00.  So basically the total number of author_IDs in 2017.

Comment: Read [ask], look at some other examples on the site, and then post a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk to check the year from column 6 to see if it is 2017, then print column 1 if it is, and use "sort -u" to find the unique entries.

e.g.

`awk -F, '$6 ~ /..?\/..?\/2017 ..?:../ {print $1}' input.csv | sort -u`

Which basically says to print the first column from any lines where the 6th column matches one or two characters followed by a / followed by any one or two characters followed by a / followed by 2017 and a space followed by any one or two characters followed by a colon followed by any two characters.

**EDIT:**
If your date range becomes more specific than an entire year (e.g. from 02/27/2016 02:35 - 10/02/2018 21:15), you can look into converting the date string (`MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM`) into an epoch timestamp (number of seconds since "the epoch") and doing a comparison on that.  `awk`'s [time functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) can be referenced for this manipulation.

Comment: Rusty, thank you for taking the time to help.  This syntax makes sense, however i am getting an error on the ~ right after the field 6.  any options on fixing that error?